# Fontaine, J.-M.; Illusie, L. p-adic periods------Does any one have the following article?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, non-archimedean-fields, paper-request

Fontaine, J.-M.; Illusie, L.
p-adic periods: A survey. (English) 
Ramanan, S. (ed.) et al., Proceedings of the Indo-French conference on geometry held in Bombay, India, 1989.

If anyone has the above paper can you please share it? Thank you.

Comment: The standard way to thank someone for an answer here, Sam, is to click in the check mark next to the answer, indicating that you "accept" the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems clear that there is no online version available, but a library can probably get a PDF copy through interlibrary loan if that's an option for you.    The detailed listing is [*here*](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1274494).   Note too that Milne's short MathSciNet review of this two-author survey concludes with the remark: "Except that it is more detailed, and does not discuss proofs, it covers much the same ground as Illusie's Bourbaki talk ...", which is freely available online [*here*](http://www.numdam.org/item/SB_1989-1990__32__325_0).  Good luck with your search.

Comment: Isn't the paper available on Fontaine's website, as mentioned in my answer?

Answer (score 4):

The desired paper is freely available on Fontaine's webpage! Here is the [first part](https://www.math.u-psud.fr/~fontaine/fillusie1.pdf), and here is the [second](https://www.math.u-psud.fr/~fontaine/fillusie2.pdf).

Comment: (And just in case the first link is broken, [this one](https://web.archive.org/web/20180924155929/https://www.math.u-psud.fr/~fontaine/fillusie1.pdf) should still work, hopefully…)